# How to display tooltip in zoomable circle graph

Tags: jquery, jsp

I have tried displaying tooltip in zoomable circle packing. I need to display it onMouseover, and i am able to get the alert but not in tooltip format.

Can someone help me to get this..

Thanks.

Comment: Share your code whatever success till now and problem you are facing

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below. Hope this helps you.

```
var data = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42];

var x = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([0, d3.max(data)])
.range([0, 420]);

var tooltip = d3.select("body")
.append("div")
.style("position", "absolute")
.style("z-index", "10")
.style("visibility", "hidden")
.style("background", "#000")
.text("a simple tooltip");

d3.select("body")
.selectAll("div")
.data(data)
.enter().append("div")
.style("width", function(d) { return x(d) + "px"; })
.text(function(d) { return d; })
.on("mouseover", function(d){tooltip.text(d); return 
 tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");})
  .on("mousemove", function(){return tooltip.style("top", (d3.event.pageY-
 10)+"px").style("left",(d3.event.pageX+10)+"px");})
  .on("mouseout", function(){return tooltip.style("visibility", 
 "hidden");});
```

The var tooltip = block is where we’re creating our tooltip itself, which is just a div that is hidden by default and positioned “above” all the elements on the page (using a high z-index value).

Once that is created, we’ve then added onto the bar chart creation code of d3.js using a number of .on method calls, which accept the appropriate event and the function to fire when that event occurs. The most crucial is in the first mouseover event function, where we specify tooltip.text(d), meaning the text of our tooltip is set to the passed in data value of d.

Here yo will get customizable div tooltips with the data we passed.